# Is it possible to register a function to preprocess log messages with Log::Log4perl?

Tags: perl, logging, log4perl

In [this example](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.46/lib/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.pm#How_can_I_drill_down_on_references_before_logging_them?):

```
$logger->debug({
    filter => \&Data::Dumper::Dumper,
    value  => $ref
});
```

I can pretty print my references instead of `ARRAY(0xFFDFKDJ)`. But it's too boring to type that long code every time. I just want:

```
$logger->preprocessor({
    filter => \&Data::Dumper::Dumper,
    value  => $ref
});

$logger->debug( $ref, $ref2 );
$logger->info( $array );
```

And `$ref`, `$ref2`, and `$array` will be dumped by Data::Dumper.

It there a way to do this?

**UPD**
With help of your answers I do the [patch](https://github.com/mschilli/log4perl/pull/63)

Now you just:

```
log4perl.appender.A1.layout=FallbackLayout
log4perl.appender.A1.layout.chain=PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.A1.layout.chain.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4perl.appender.A1.warp_message = sub { $#_ = 2 if @_ > 3; \
                                       return @_; }
# OR
log4perl.appender.A1.warp_message = main::warp_my_message

sub warp_my_message {
    my( @chunks ) =  @_;

    use Data::Dump qw/ pp /;
    for my $msg ( @chunks ) {
        $msg =  pp $msg   if ref $msg;
    }

    return @chunks;
}
```

**UPD2**

Or you can use this small module

```
log4perl.appender.SomeAPP.warp_message  = Preprocess::Messages::msg_filter
log4perl.appender.SomeAPP.layout        = Preprocess::Messages

package Preprocess::Messages;

sub msg_filter {
    my @chunks =  @_;

    for my $msg ( @chunks ) {
        $msg =  pp $msg   if ref $msg;
    }

    return @chunks;
};

sub render {
    my $self =  shift;

    my $layout =  Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new(
        '%d %P %p> %c %F:%L %M%n  %m{indent=2}%n%n'
    );

    $_[-1] += 1; # increase level of the caller
    return $layout->render( join $Log::Log4perl::JOIN_MSG_ARRAY_CHAR, @{ shift() }, @_ );
}


sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    $class = ref ($class) || $class;

    return bless {}, $class;
}

1;
```

Yes, of course you can set 'warp_message = 0' and combine msg_filter and render together.

```
log4perl.appender.SomeAPP.warp_message  = 0
log4perl.appender.SomeAPP.layout        = Preprocess::Messages

sub render {
    my($self, $message, $category, $priority, $caller_level) = @_;

    my $layout =  Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new(
        '%d %P %p> %c %F:%L %M%n  %m{indent=2}%n%n'
    );

    for my $item ( @{ $message } ) {
        $item =  pp $item   if ref $item;
    }

    $message =  join $Log::Log4perl::JOIN_MSG_ARRAY_CHAR, @$message;
    return $layout->render( $message, $category, $priority, $caller_level+1 );
}
```

Comment: I think you could make a custom appender and call that, if I remember correctly. Cannot find my old code, but there is an indent example in the docs, I think you could just make a log sub that dumps if ref() eq 'ARRAY'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The easy way: use `warp_message`

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom appender and [set the `warp_message` parameter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Appender#Appenders-Expecting-Message-Chunks) so you can get the original references that were passed to the logger:

```
package DumpAppender;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;

sub new {
    bless {}, $_[0];
}

sub log {
    my($self, %params) = @_;
    print ref($_) ? Dumper($_) : $_ for @{ $params{message} };
    print "\n";
}

package main;   
use strict;
use warnings;

use Log::Log4perl;

Log::Log4perl->init(\q{
    log4perl.rootLogger=DEBUG,Dump
    log4perl.appender.Dump=DumpAppender
    log4perl.appender.Dump.layout=NoopLayout
    log4perl.appender.Dump.warp_message=0
});

my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger;

$logger->debug(
    'This is a string, but this is a reference: ',
    { foo => 'bar' },
);
```

#### Output:

```
This is a string, but this is a reference: {'foo' => 'bar'}
```

Unfortunately, if you take this approach, you're stuck writing your own code to handle layouts, open files, etc. I wouldn't take this approach except for very simple projects that only need to print to screen.

## A better way: composite appender

A better approach is to write your own [composite appender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Appender#Composite-Appenders). A composite appender forwards messages on to another appender after manipulating them somehow, e.g. filtering or caching them. With this approach, you can write only the code for dumping the references and let an existing appender do the heavy lifting.

The following shows how to write a composite appender. Some of this is explained in the docs for [Log::Log4perl::Appender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Appender#Composite-Appenders), but I copied much of it from Mike Schilli's [Log::Log4perl::Appender::Limit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Appender::Limit):

```
package DumpAppender;   
use strict;
use warnings;

our @ISA = qw(Log::Log4perl::Appender);

use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;

sub new {
    my ($class, %options) = @_;

    my $self = {
        appender => undef,
        %options
    };

    # Pass back the appender to be limited as a dependency to the configuration
    # file parser.
    push @{ $options{l4p_depends_on} }, $self->{appender};

    # Run our post_init method in the configurator after all appenders have been
    # defined to make sure the appenders we're connecting to really exist.
    push @{ $options{l4p_post_config_subs} }, sub { $self->post_init() };

    bless $self, $class;
}

sub log {
    my ($self, %params) = @_;

    # Adjust call stack so messages are reported with the correct caller and
    # file
    local $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth = $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth + 2;

    # Dump all references with Data::Dumper
    $_ = ref($_) ? Dumper($_) : $_ for @{ $params{message} };

    $self->{app}->SUPER::log(
        \%params,
        $params{log4p_category},
        $params{log4p_level}
    );
}

sub post_init {
    my ($self) = @_;

    if(! exists $self->{appender}) {
        die "No appender defined for " . __PACKAGE__;
    }

    my $appenders = Log::Log4perl->appenders();
    my $appender = Log::Log4perl->appenders()->{$self->{appender}};

    if(! defined $appender) {
        die "Appender $self->{appender} not defined (yet) when " .
            __PACKAGE__ . " needed it";
    }

    $self->{app} = $appender;
}

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Log::Log4perl;

Log::Log4perl->init(\q{
    log4perl.rootLogger=DEBUG, Dump

    log4perl.appender.Dump=DumpAppender
    log4perl.appender.Dump.appender=SCREEN

    log4perl.appender.SCREEN=Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
    log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout=PatternLayout
    log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %m%n
});

my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger;

$logger->debug(
    'This is a string, but this is a reference: ',
    { foo => 'bar' },
);
```

#### Output:

```
2015/09/14 13:38:47 DEBUG This is a string, but this is a reference: {'foo' => 'bar'}
```

Note that you have to take some extra steps if you initialize Log::Log4perl via the API instead of via a file. This is documented in the [composite appenders](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Appender#Composite-Appenders) section of the Log::Log4perl::Appender documentation.